special_tokens parameter of SentencePieceBPETokenizer.train_from_iterator()
I want to train a custom tokenizer from scratch. Following some online tutorials, they suggest adding a series of special tokens to the train_from_iterator() function:
special_tokens = ["<unk>", "<pad>", "<cls>", "<sep>", "<mask>", "<s>", "</s>"]
tokenizer = SentencePieceBPETokenizer()
tokenizer.train_from_iterator(
    get_training_corpus(),
    vocab_size = 100000,
    min_frequency = 1000, # min number of occurrence before adding into vocab list
    special_tokens = special_tokens
)

My question: Is there any specific order to list the tokens? How does the SentencePieceBPETokenizer map the special tokens with corresponding string, for example: unk_token maps with <unk>, cls_token maps with <cls> in the special_tokens list.
Working with the HuggingFace example run_translation.py, I tried to compare the output file of special_tokens_map.json of a BART base tokenizer and my custom tokenizer, and found out that the structure is very different. See below:

Left: BART Base Tokenizer (from HuggingFace fnlp/bart-base-chinese); Right: my custom tokenizer generated by the SentencePieceBPETokenizer.train_from_iterator()
How can my custom tokenizer generate the same special_tokens_map.json as the BART base tokenizer? The generated config.json using both tokenizers are almost identical, except for the vocab_size.
Tracing back the source code, the BpeTrainer class in the Rust language does not specify how the training process maps the tokens.
Or, shouldn't I use SentencePieceBPETokenizer?
